# How to apply parsley in a ajax loaded page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to apply validation for datepicker in a ajax loaded content. But validation is not working for the loaded content.Please help

/*Script*/

```
function get_period(feestype)  
{  

    jQuery.ajax({
    url:"../js/lib/datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
    datatype:"script"
    }).done(function(){

    jQuery.ajax({
    url:"../js/lib/parsley/parsley.min.js",
    datatype:"script"
    }).done(function(){

    jQuery.ajax({
    url:"../js/pages/form_validate.js",
    datatype:"script"
    }).done(function(){
    $.ajax({  
        type: "GET",  
        url: "feesperiod.php",  
        data: "feestype="+feestype, 
        success: function(msg){  
         $("#period_div").html(msg).find('.datepicker').datepicker({ inline:true });
        }  
    });  

    });
    });
    });      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**.done(function()** You are not return anything, you can't use any function from **bootstrap-datepicker.js**, **parsley.min.js**